# Cannot make executable jar using m2eclipse

Tags: maven, manifest, m2eclipse

I have just started learning how to use m2eclipse. What I am trying to do is make a very simple program (Hello, World) and turn it into an executable jar. The java code itself is:

public class Speak {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Meow!");
}

}
```

which runs fine as a Java application. I then try to use Maven to build the program, which it does, but then when I try to run the .jar it tells me "Failed to load Main-Class attribute from ...". This is the .pom that m2eclipse generated when I started the project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org   /2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.felines</groupId>
<artifactId>tabbies</artifactId>
<version>0.0</version>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
  <type>maven-plugin</type>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

I have tried modifying the .pom, like so:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.felines</groupId>
<artifactId>tabbies</artifactId>
<version>0.0</version>
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <configuration>
        <archive>
        <manifest>
             <mainClass>org.felines.Speak</mainClass>
             <packageName>org.felines</packageName>
        </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <mode>development</mode>
                <url>${pom.url}</url>
        </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Now it says "Could not find the main class: org.felines.Speak. Program will exit." Any ideas? :(

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What is the package statement in your Speak class?

Comment: I figured for such a simple program I could use the default package so there is no package statement. Is that where I went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pom.xml you state that the main class should be `org.felines.Speak`. But the class is actually in the default package, meaning no package definition. So either set the package to `org.felines` in the class implementation or change your `mainClass` entry in the pom.xml to `Speak` alone. Then the necessary information to start the jar should be available.