# What is the correct way to specify a main class when packaging a jar using m2eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse, maven-eclipse-plugin

**Problem:** 
I'd like to specify the main class in a jar file that I am packaging using m2eclipse: [right-click] -> Run As -> Maven package.  I'm still learning Maven and from what I've read, the straight-up way of accomplishing this task is to add a stanza to the pom.xml.
Here are examples I found when I was researched this issue:

- [Cannot make executable jar using m2eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060422/cannot-make-executable-jar-using-m2eclipse)
- http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=72602

**My question is this:** is it okay to manually edit the pom.xml file outside of Eclipse/m2eclipse using a text editor, or should I be doing this configuration using the m2ecplise GUI?  There are several tabbed dialog boxes that seem like they might be likely candidates for this task, like "Plugins" and "Build".  I looked through Sonatype's documentation and couldn't find any detailed instructions on how to accomplish what I need to do.

I'm a little hesitant to edit the pom.xml manually because I notice the "Effective POM" already has a lot of extra stuff in it, including the plugin definition that needs to have  added to it:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-jar</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

If I understand correctly, the Effective POM needs to be changed so that the plugin is configured like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-jar</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
    <archive>
    <manifest>
         <mainClass>[name of main class]</mainClass>
         <packageName>[package name]</packageName>
    </manifest>
        <manifestEntries>
            <mode>development</mode>
            <url>${pom.url}</url>
    </manifestEntries>
    </archive>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Is this right?  And if so, do I do this through m2eclipse or should I just copy all the extra Effective POM stuff and paste it into the actual pom.xml using a text editor?

Thanks to anyone who can shed some light.

**UPDATE:** I went ahead and manually edited the pom.xml file in a text editor.  When I viewed Effective POM in m2eclipse it displayed everything that I put in (I assume).  I built the jar and the main class was correctly set.

This seems like a hack to me though.  Does anyone know if there's a way to do this configuration using m2eclipse itself?  I checked the m2eclipse tabs and nothing seemed to have been updated as a result of my manual edits of pom.xml (other than the Effective POM tab).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

m2eclipse doesn't do everything for you, i.e. there isn't a pretty UI tab for handling *everything*.

My team is most comfortable with editing the POM manually, and using the other tabs for verification (like Effective POM view).

Comment: Hi John, thanks, that's what I needed to know.  I'm starting my study of Maven now and will go ahead and do most of my configurations manually.  Good to know that I wasn't missing something and hacking files that weren't meant to be edited directly.